# IBM DB2 SQL Connection Errors

Tags: db2

I can connect to IBM DB2 inside the IBM Cloud Pak for Data, but when I try to run the exact same %sql connection it errors out. What am I missing?

'''%sql ibm_db_sa://un:pw@host:port/db?security=SSL'''

(ibm_db_dbi.Error) ibm_db_dbi::Error: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL5005C  The operation failed because the database manager failed to access either the database manager configuration file or the database configuration file.\r SQLCODE=-5005
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

[IBM DB2 SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQF2L.png)

Comment: What is the `%sql` magic based on? Did you pass in the correct username and password? Is the driver loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure about the driver, but the username/pw is accurate. When I use the same connection string in the IBM Cloud Data Pak it works perfectly. Outside of the IBM portal and when using VS Code, it is not working.

Comment: How would I find what the %sql is based on?

Comment: Is the driver (ibm_db, ibm_db_sa) available outside the Cloud Pak environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the package ibm_db