# IBM DB2 Connections

Tags: python, db2, ibm-cloud

Why can I connect to my sql db2 while using jupyter notebooks in ibm cloud but when I try to run the same connection string in ms vs code I get an error?

'''%sql ibm_db_sa://un:pw@host:port/db?security=SSL'''

(ibm_db_dbi.Error) ibm_db_dbi::Error: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL5005C The operation failed because the database manager failed to access either the database manager configuration file or the database configuration file.\r SQLCODE=-5005 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi) Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example: postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IBM DB2 SQL Connection Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72421665/ibm-db2-sql-connection-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you specify what is ms?
Also please try to reach the dba admin to verify the user account has the correct privileges to access to the database.
If you are trying to connect in remote mode from a Linux environment you will need a SSL certificate to ensure the correct connection.
And check if the instance is UP and if not try to run db2start.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case
I got error

SQL0332N  Character conversion from the source code page "874"
to the target code page "1252" is not supported.  SQLCODE=-332

I found the codepage of table is 874
and my OS is not set non-Unicode so I go to the Region setting and
I solved this by changing at 'Language for non-Unicoded programs'
from English(United States) to Thai(Thailand)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).